# System monitor doesn't provide correct information

Tags: system-monitor

I often see that my System Monitor doesn't give me exact information about internet downloading and uploading speed. It shows different value from graph. A snapshot looks like -[image]

Here, the graph is saying value less than 0.6 MB/s but the text bellow the graph is saying that the download speed is 1.8MB/s.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Why the mismatch?

Comment: The current value on the graph is on the *right*. That point on the graph is showing 1.8 Mbps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red line is the upload speed, the blue line is the download speed.

The blue line does in fact match the text underneath. Keep in mind that the right end of the graph is the present, while the left end is the past.